# Using an update query with multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have a column of ZIP codes, some of which I need to add a leading zero to in order to make it five digits and some of which are blank and need to be populated with five zeroes. How do I do both in one update query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate 5 zeroes to the start of the Zip code value, and take the right-most 5 characters from that combined string.

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET zip_code = Right('00000' & zip_code, 5)
WHERE Len(Trim(zip_code & '')) < 5;
```

I assumed the `zip_code` field is text type because storing leading zeroes doesn't make sense for numeric data.  If the field is numeric, you could just use a `Format()` expression to display the leading zeroes.

The `WHERE` clause limits the `UPDATE` to only those rows where `zip_code` is Null or less than 5 characters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. An additional issue I neglected to mention is that some of the fields have the ZIP +4, which I want to retain. I just need all of the ZIPs to have at least five digits.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause excludes rows whose `zip_code` values include 5 or more characters.  So your stored ZIP+4 values will not be changed.  Is there a problem I'm not seeing?